# R - Vennerable error

Tags: r, venn-diagram

I am getting the following error when trying to make Venn diagram with Vennerable.

```
library(Vennerable)
A <- c("123","234")
B <- c("567","234")
C <- c("987","234")
l1 <- list(aa = A, bb = B, cc = C)
v1 <- Venn(l1)

Error in rep(1, nrow(Indicator)) : invalid 'times' argument
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Vivek

Comment: Vennerable package is not available for R 3.0. If you can the post the expected output, some other package can be suggested.

Comment: Your code works for me. Try updating: `install.packages("Vennerable", repos="http://R-Forge.R-project.org")`

Answer (score 0):

It turns out this code works fine on my mac, but not my home computer running Windows7... very weird.